# Getting the button that opened modal (NOT with data-* html tag)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

I have a bootstrap modal that is opened on click by two different buttons.
if a given condition is met for instatnce:

```
$('#buttonName').on('click', function (e) {
     var arg = something;
     if (condition) {
     $('#modalName').modal('show');
     } else { someFunction(arg); }
});

$('#otherButton').on('click', function (e) {
     var arg = something;
     if (condition) {
     $('#modalName').modal('show');
     } else { someFunction(arg); }
});
```

HTML data attribute cannot be used here. So something like this:

```
<button id="buttonName" class="modalBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalName" data-caller="button1"></button>
```

will not work because *if* statement from *on.click* event is then omitted and modal is open regardless of the condition, which I don't want.

The modal contains a button

```
<div id="logoutBoxModal" class="modal fade bd-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="true" keyboard:="true">
    <div id="" class="modal-content">                   
        <button id="modalButton"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

that supposed to do something based on which of the two buttons opened it.

I tried this:

```
//$('#myModal') alternatively
$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var $trigger = e.relatedTarget;
    console.log($trigger);
});
```

but it always returns *undefined*.

All answers I could find involved usage of data attribute which cannot be used here.

To sum it up essentially all I need is how do I pass a value to the modal so that it can tell the button what it should do, and all has to be done with javascript/jquery.

Thanks

**UPDATE - Answer**

Returned `$trigger` variable is Javascript not jQuery and it's data can be accessed with Javascript:

```
<button id="buttonName" class="modalBtn" data-caller="button1"></button>

 var $trigger = e.relatedTarget.target;
 var data = $trigger.dataset.caller;
 console.log(data);
```

to contrary of jQuery:

```
...
var data = $trigger.data("caller");
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `$('#modalName').modal('show');`, pass a second argument.

Example:

```
$('#modalName').modal('show', {target: e.target});
```

`e.relatedTarget` should now be the object with target assigned to `e.target` (or whatever you choose to pass).

Edit (per comments):

```
$('#buttonName').on('click', function (e) {
    var arg = something;
    if (condition) {
        // Pass target in click-event handler
        $('#modalName').modal('show', {target: e.target});
    } else {
        someFunction(arg);
    }
});

$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var $trigger = e.relatedTarget.target;
    console.log($trigger);
});
```

Comment: And how exactly would I access the { target: ...} from within inside-modal button.
    $('#modalButton').on('click', function (e) {
        ???
    });

Cheers

Comment: Hi @dozobus, `target` would be accessed within your `show.bs.modal` handler. You would pass `target` from the `click` handler. Updated answer with example.

Comment: Yes sir, it worked. As a side note, for those interested the returned variable `var $trigger` is javascript object not jQuery. See my updated question.
Thank you for help Jack